# EmberJS "set" method on object doesn't seems to work when uses filter with Ember Data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Aloha folks:

I am kinda newbie to EmberJS, I've found something weird here, looking for a superhero can save me here :)

This code is just a copy from the EmberJS doc: [Ember Method Filter](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_filter)

```
store.filter('post', {unread: true}, function(post) {
  return post.get('unread');
}).then(function(unreadPosts) {
  unreadPosts.get('length'); // 5
  var unreadPost = unreadPosts.objectAt(0);
  unreadPost.set('unread', false);
  unreadPosts.get('length'); // not 4 but 5       <---- I console logged here
});
```

When I try to do exactly the same thing, my **console.log(unreadPosts.get('length'))** after the set unread to false is not changed to 4, it stays 5.

And I also found that once that unreadPost get set unread to false, {unread: false} get added to "**_attributes**" on this unreadPost, but the **data** of this unreadPost object remains the same as:

```
{
id: "1"
unread: true
}
```

But, however if I do this:

```
store.filter('post', {unread: true}, function(post) {
  return post.get('unread');
}).then(function(unreadPosts) {
  unreadPosts.get('length'); // 5
  var unreadPost = unreadPosts.objectAt(0);
  unreadPost.set('unread', false);
});

store.filter('post', {unread: true}, function(post) {
  return post.get('unread');
}).then(function(unreadPosts) {
  unreadPosts.get('length'); // 4   <---- this console.log will give me 4
});
```

Did I missed anything or did I do wrong here that seems to me set in this situation is not work as "EmberJS doc example" suggested?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filters are updated asynchronously.  Setting a property doesn't guarantee that the collection will be immediately updated.  Something like what's implemented below should give you an updated collection.

```
store.filter('post', {unread: true}, function(post) {
  return post.get('unread');
}).then(function(unreadPosts) {
  unreadPosts.get('length'); // 5
  var unreadPost = unreadPosts.objectAt(0);
  unreadPost.set('unread', false);
  Em.run.next(function(){
    unreadPosts.get('length'); // not 4 but 5       <---- I console logged here
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @kingpin2k that works for me!
I guess the Ember website's example maybe is for the previous release of Ember, and its lack of update...

Comment: Np, do you have a link, it'd be worth updating the documentation.

Comment: It's up on this post, or use this link: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_filter
Thanks!